# How to pass a variable from activities to start a CountDownTimer service?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service

This is my first question and I've been trying to find a solution to this for hours but can't get it to work. I'm building an android app that takes an input from the user (number of hours) to fast (not eat). The input is then taken to the service where it does a countdown in the background. Along the way, I'd like the user to access other activities that could you the results from the countdown timer (eg, time_left/total_time = percentage complete). So far, my button that I've created works to make the call for the service. but the service never gets called to update the text view. Thanks

Here is what I have,

```
public class StartFast extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_fast);
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        Log.i("Started service", "hello started service...");
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("COUNTDOWN_UPDATED"));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            intent.getExtras();
            long millisUntilFinished = intent.getLongExtra("countdown",0);
            String time = Long.toString((millisUntilFinished));
            TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.timeView1);
            tv.setText(time);
        }
    };

    public void BeginFast(View view){
        //Intent intent = new Intent( this, StartFast.class);
        // below is how to pass an intent for use in a Service to run in the backgroun
       Intent intent =new Intent(this, MyService.class);
       startService(intent);
         //   intent.putExtra() // putExtra longs ...will do after static run succeeds
        //intent.putExtra("data", data); //adding the data

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Heart.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
}
```

and here is the service class,

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final static String TAG = "MyService";
    public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "FastBreak.countdown_br";
    Intent bi = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);
    CountDownTimer cdt = null;

    public void OnCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        Log.i(TAG, "starting timer...");
        cdt = new CountDownTimer(30000,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " +millisUntilFinished /1000);
                bi.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
                sendBroadcast(bi);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish(){
                Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
            }
        };
        cdt.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        cdt.cancel();
        Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelled");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting a broadcast call? + Have you declare service in menifesst?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Check this out. This library is the best and easiest implementation of broadcasts. You can send any data to any object (StartFast service in your case) from any other object (StartFast activity in your case) and write code to run.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to start the service and register it in the manifest. After the service is started by an activity, it will keep running in the background.

You can send intents with a service and anybody who has registered a broadcast receiver listening to that intent can hear it.

Let's say FirstActivity started the service and registers receiver listening to intent with the tag BOBBY. The service is the one sending an intent BOBBY to anyone who is interested and has registered for it.

You want to move on to SecondActivity. Before you do that, onPause of FirstActivity you need to unregister that broadcastreceiver.

SecondActivity is interested in the intent with tag BOBBY, so he creates his own broadcast receiver and registers for it.

I hope you can see where this is going.A broadcastreceiver can listen to all sorts of intents that you make up.

Have fun.